# UIView inside a table view cell does not resize to UIScreen.main.bounds

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitableview

I have a table view cell where I am playing a video in a `UIView`. On the `UIView` I have a full screen button. On click of the button I want the `UIView` to take up the entire screen, so I am doing the following:

```
cell?.videoView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
```

But the `UIView` resizes itself only to the content view of that particular cell not to the entire phone screen.

Comment: make sure the cell and cell.contentView clipsToBounds = false, if you tableview is not fullscreen you may also have to do it on this.

Comment: Why do you set a subview bigger than the cell ? Try to add the view directly on the tableView Controller. Otherwise check the clipToBounds property on the cell.CententView, the tableView, the cell, and the cell.BackgroundView

Comment: On the button click just increase the height of the cell and then call `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` or reload the row.

Comment: @SeanLintern88 the default value for `clipsToBounds ` property is `false`.

Comment: @AhmadF except when you make a cell with a Nib? on the Nib the clips to bounds is always ticked

Comment: I don't think it's possible to increase a cell content to fullscreen. Just think about it. UIViews starting from the window have a z-order, so even if you achieve to make the content larger than the cell, the previous or next cell content might have a higher z-order (is shown above your view). You can't change this order because it's UITableView internal logic. I think you have to change you concept. Maybe you have to switch the view or move the view outside the UITableView...